# .htaccess redirect - how to go from /about to /our-story

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to make it so that anything at /about goes to /our-story.

I think my .htaccess redirect rule is correct for this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

The line is here:

```
RewriteRule ^about.*$ http://domain.com/our-story/ [R=301,L]


</IfModule>
```

However it doesn't seem to work. My suspicion is that this is due to Wordpress being active. I tried to put it inside the Wordpress block though, and still it doesn't work.

What do I have to do to redirect from `/about` to `/our-story`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is correct, but they need to go *before* the wordpress rules because you are redirecting while the wordpress rules routes everything into `/index.php`. Any request URI that starts with `/about` will end up getting routed to wordpress and thus never get redirected. Just switch the order:

```
RewriteRule ^about.*$ http://domain.com/our-story/ [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```